# Laravel checkbox $request issue

Tags: laravel

I am trying to pass 2 array of checkboxes, to my controller: roles and permissions to insert and/or patch in DB.

in my controller I am passing the collections to display on blade:

```
$roles = Role::all();
$permissions = Permission::all();
```

and all works fine as it displays the name and the checkbox.
Yet 2 issues when submitting:

- $request is showing a simple array for each **without** the name of the role/permission.
- I do not get an "off" for non checked.

http://prntscr.com/jq61p6

I am expecting to insert/patch roles and permissions for a specific `$user->id`.

I am assuming the problem is in blade and in my checkbox inputs:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('roles-permissions',['id' =>$user->id]) }}">
            {{ csrf_field() }}

        <h5>User Roles</h5>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @foreach ($roles as $role)
                {{ Form::checkbox('roles[]',  null, true, ['class' => 'name'] ) }}
                {{ Form::label($role->name, ucfirst($role->name)) }}<br>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        <div class="break-20"></div>
        <h5>User Permissions</h5>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
                {{ Form::checkbox('permissions[]', null , false, ['class' => 'name']) }}
                {{ Form::label($permission->name, ucfirst($permission->name)) }}<br>
            @endforeach
        </div>
        {!! Form::submit('Save Roles and Permissions', ['class=', '"btn btn-primary width-250 mt-20"']); !!}

        </form>
```

How can I fix this so I can see the role and permission name so I can pick up the right permissions/roles by my controller and save them into my roles/user and permissions/user tables?

Thanks.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html#form-model-binding

Answer (score 0):

3rd argument will decide whether it will be checked or not. Use `null` instead of `true` & let's check whether it works or not.

Comment: nope, but TBH, I can live with only "on", but as you can see from my screenshot, I do not get the actual name of the role/permission in the request dump, how would I fix that?

Comment: first argument will decide input field name. in your case, it's roles & permissions. what is your expected result?

Comment: I put in the 2nd arg the `$permission->name` and I am getting it right, I actually don't need on. 

I just need to check 2 things: would I be able to save to DB and would it be able to retrieve from DB. I'll update here with a comment.